# How many monotonically increasing(not strictly) functions between two sets with a simple condition

Tags: combinatorics

The question is:

How many monotonically increasing(not strictly) functions are there from the set $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,7, 8\}$ in itself such that $f(4) = 4$?

Can someone explain why the what is wrong with the answer $\binom{8+7-1}{7}$?

I'm counting all the multisets which contain at least one $4$ which is the equivalent of counting all multisets of size 7 which can contain all the elements from the codomain.

Correct answer is $\binom{5}{2}$$\binom{7}{3}$

I understand why is the product rule used with the reasoning of the solution, but not why is it used in the first place.

In the answer the idea was to look at two monotonically increasing(not strictly) functions which are: $g$ which maps $\{1, 2, 3\}$ in itself and $h$ which maps $\{5, 6, 7, 8\}$ in itself. Why is the $4$ not included here and why do we even have to use this reasoning here as opposed to my reasoning?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your idea here was to take an eight-element multiset $\{n_1, \ldots, n_8\}$ with the elements in ascending order, and then assign $f(1) = n_1$, $f(2) = n_2$, and so on. Then a multiset that contains at least one $4$ corresponds to a function $f$ with a 4 *somewhere* in its image: that is, $f(k) = 4$ for some integer $k$. But this doesn't mean necessarily that $f(4) = 4$: you could have any value of $k$ instead. So your method will create a large overcount.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I was thinking that f(k)=4 is the same as f(4)=4 because the order of elements doesn't matter but with this condition it clearly does. But why aren't we considering $4$ when were are counting $g$ and $h$? It is not stated in the problem that the 4 can only be used once in the image.

Comment: @small_k I think you're right - the answer should be $\binom{6}{3} \binom{8}{4}$.